# Calculate period start and end date

Tags: teradata

My table:

```
Date       Employee     Status
-----------------------------
20171106   001          At work
20171107   001          Sick leave
20171108   001          At work
20171109   001          At work
20171111   001          Sick leave (A gap here)
20171112   001          Sick leave
20171115   001          At work (Another gap)
20171116   001          At work
```

Desired result:

```
Employee      Status        StartDT                       EndDT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
001           At work       Some time in the history      20171106
001           Sick leave    20171107                      20171107
001           At work       20171108                      20171109
001           Sick leave    20171111                      20171112
001           At work       20171115                      20171116
```

The logic: We re-organize the source table by status, not by date. So a gap in date does not matter and should be ignored.

How to do this in Teradata 15?

Note: `select min(Date), max(Date) group by employee, status;` will not work, as there may be status change between two "At work"s.

Comment: Is there a row for each day or are there gaps? What's the datatype of `Date`?

Comment: @dnoeth there may be gaps, for example weekends are not in the table. It only records workdays. Date is of type `date`.

Comment: re: gaps ... are they to be ignored, or considered?  you may want to add some more sample data that shows what happens when a gap (eg, weekend/holiday) has 2 different status as box ends (eg, Fri=Sick Leave, Mon=At work)

Comment: @markp we should ignore gaps. Please see my updated question for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution normalizes a period:

```
SELECT NORMALIZE Employee, Status, PERIOD(date,date+1) AS pd
FROM mytable
ORDER BY Employee, pd
```

`NORMALIZE` is a very unknown syntax, it combines overlapping periods, you just need to create a one day period out of the date column. As this results in a period you get a slightly different output, the end date is +1 compared to the expected result.

To fix this you can split the period back into seperate columns:

```
SELECT Employee, Status, Begin(pd), 
   Last(pd) -- last included date, i.e. expected EndDT
FROM
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE Employee, Status, PERIOD(date,date+1) AS pd
   FROM myTable
 ) AS dt
ORDER BY 1,pd
```

Getting this *Some time in the history* is more complicated, would need additional calculations, you should check if you really need it.

Another more classical solution calculates groups of rows with  consecutive values:

```
SELECT Employee, Status, Min(date), Max(date)
FROM
 (
   SELECT Employee, Status, date, 
   -- this is the tricky part, the differnce between a monotonous sequence (row_number) 
   -- and another monotonous sequence with gaps (date)
   -- is constant when there's no gap
      date - Row_Number() 
             Over (PARTITION BY Employee, Status
                   ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM vt
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY Employee, Status, grp
ORDER BY 3
```

Both solution will result in an extra row when you add

```
20171120   001          At work
...
001           At work       20171115                      20171116
001           At work       20171120                      20171120
```

If you want to combine with the previous row

```
001           At work       20171115                      20171120
```

it's also a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a Teradata system (and my Teradata 'knowledge' is extremely old/outdated) so the below code was tested against SQL Server.

NOTE: I'm assuming a (relatively) minor issue to convert to Teradata syntax ...

We'll start with our table and sample data:

```
create table emp_status
([Date]     date
,Employee   varchar(10)
,Status     varchar(30));

insert into emp_status values
('20171106','001','At work'),
('20171107','001','Sick leave'),
('20171108','001','At work'),
('20171109','001','At work'),
('20171111','001','Sick leave'),
('20171112','001','Sick leave'),
('20171115','001','At work'),
('20171116','001','At work');
```

To make the query a bit easier to write we'll **expand** our source data by adding add some temporary 'start' and 'end' records for each `Employee`.

The 'start' record will duplicate the earliest `Status` but with `Date=18000101`, while the 'end' record will set `Status='BOGUS'` and `Date=99991231`:

```
-- with expanded as ...

select [Date],
       Employee,
       Status
from   emp_status

union all

-- add our starting/history record

select distinct
       '18000101',
       es1.Employee,
       es1.Status
from   emp_status es1
where  [Date] = (select min(es2.[Date])
                 from   emp_status es2
                 where  es2.Employee = es1.Employee)

union all

-- add our ending record

select distinct
       '99991231',
       Employee,
       'BOGUS'
from   emp_status

 Date                | Employee | Status    
 ------------------- | -------- | ----------
 01/01/1800 00:00:00 | 001      | At work     <--- temporary 'start' record
 06/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | At work   
 07/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | Sick leave
 08/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | At work   
 09/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | At work   
 11/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | Sick leave
 12/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | Sick leave
 15/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | At work   
 16/11/2017 00:00:00 | 001      | At work   
 31/12/9999 00:00:00 | 001      | BOGUS       <-- temporary 'end' record
```

The next step is to use our **expanded** source data to come up with a **range** for each data record.

While the beginning of each range will simply be `Date`, the upper limit for each record will be determined by a) finding the `Date` for the next (different) `Status` and then b) subtracting 1 day from said `Date`:

```
-- with ranges   as ...

select curr.Employee,
       curr.Status,
       curr.[Date],
       dateadd(day,-1,min(change.[Date])) as maxDate

from   expanded curr

left
join   expanded change

on     curr.Employee  = change.Employee
and    curr.Status   != change.Status
and    curr.[Date]    < change.[Date]

group by curr.Employee,
         curr.[Date],
         curr.Status

 Employee | Status     | Date                | maxDate            
 -------- | ---------- | ------------------- | -------------------
 001      | At work    | 01/01/1800 00:00:00 | 06/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | At work    | 06/11/2017 00:00:00 | 06/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | Sick leave | 07/11/2017 00:00:00 | 07/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | At work    | 08/11/2017 00:00:00 | 10/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | At work    | 09/11/2017 00:00:00 | 10/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | Sick leave | 11/11/2017 00:00:00 | 14/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | Sick leave | 12/11/2017 00:00:00 | 14/11/2017 00:00:00
 001      | At work    | 15/11/2017 00:00:00 | 30/12/9999 00:00:00
 001      | At work    | 16/11/2017 00:00:00 | 30/12/9999 00:00:00
 001      | BOGUS      | 31/12/9999 00:00:00 | null
```

The last part is to group these **ranges** by `maxDate`, discarding the `Status=BOGUS` record, and doing some data conversions to 'pretty print' the results as per the desired output displayed in the question.

We do need to join back to our **expanded** data so as to get a valid `EndDt` (**ranges.maxDate** isn't necessarily a valid date since we merely subtracted one day without verifying said day is an actual `Date` value):

```
-- with expanded as ...
-- with ranges   as ...

select  r.Employee,
        r.Status,
        case min(r.[Date])  
             when '18000101'
             then 'Some time in the history'
             else convert(varchar(30),min(r.[Date]),112)
        end                                                 as StartDT,
        convert(varchar(8),max(e.[Date]),112)               as EndDT

from   ranges r
join   expanded e

on     r.Employee  = e.Employee
and    r.Status    = e.Status
and    r.[Date]    = e.[Date]
and    r.maxDate  >= e.[Date]

and    r.Status   != 'BOGUS'

group by r.Employee,
         r.Status,
         r.maxDate

order by 1,4

 Employee | Status     | StartDT                  | EndDT
 -------- | ---------- | ------------------------ | --------
 001      | At work    | Some time in the history | 20171106
 001      | Sick leave | 20171107                 | 20171107
 001      | At work    | 20171108                 | 20171109
 001      | Sick leave | 20171111                 | 20171112
 001      | At work    | 20171115                 | 20171116
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c2bd15583e16641602312734e9bad5b) of the above.

---

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, and after congealing in the background I may think of something else, but for now I wanted to get this (brute force?) idea jotted down ... and perhaps someone can use this as a jumping off point for that more efficient method ...